# MySql query BETWEEN two Strings sometimes doesn't work

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query where a subquery is:

```
BETWEEN '5.00' AND '10.00'
```

And this returns no results.

However when I use Floats or Ints:

```
BETWEEN 5 and 10
```

it works

The BETWEEN query also works for other values AS strings, but just not for 5 and 10.

EG:

```
BETWEEN '4' AND '5'
```

works.

How could this be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a difference between strings and integers *-- there is a reason why you have several different datatypes* :

When comparing **integers**, you are comparing their **numerical values** ; i.e. `10` is bigger than `5`.

When comparing **strings**, you are using an **alphabetical comparison** ; i.e. `'10'` is smaller than `'5'`, because `'1'` is smaller than `'5'`.