# how can i retrieve the records from table using between operator in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

everybody

I want to retrieve the records from a table(price) based on the following query.My table is

```
+-----------+
| pprice    |
+-----------+
| 10 lakhs  |
| 11 lakhs  |
| 12 crores |
| 13 lakhs  |
| 15 crores |
| 16 lakhs  |
+-----------+
```

I'm using the following query

```
select * from price where pprice between '10 lakhs' and '20 lakhs';
```

but it returns the following result

```
+-----------+
| pprice    |
+-----------+
| 10 lakhs  |
| 11 lakhs  |
| 12 crores |
| 13 lakhs  |
| 15 crores |
| 16 lakhs  |
+-----------+
```

what's the problem in my query.please give me reply for this.

Comment: Between function doesn't work with `varchar` column type. You need to change your column type from `varchar` to any numerical column type. For that you also have to update all rows.

Comment: @hims056: what do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: This is inappropriate use of database. Numeric values such as price should be stored in pure numbers like 100000 (and not like 10 million or 10 lakhs). I recommend that instead of continuing like this, you should spend some time in updating all such values in the database by writing and executing some queries manually.

Comment: @zerkms - Doesn't work means `BETWEEN` can't understand words. So it won't give you expected result.

Comment: @hims056: it does support string types. Please bother looking at least at documentation next time you're arguing: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with **equal** magnitudes, such as lakhs in your example, you can do something like this:

```
select *
  from price
 where pprice between '10 lakhs' and '20 lakhs'
   and pprice like '__ lakhs';
```

Answer (score 0):

When we ares comparing integers, we are comparing their `numerical` values ;

i.e. 10 >  6.

When we are comparing strings, we are using an `alphabetical` comparison ;

i.e. '10'<  '6'

[**SEE HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434249/mysql-query-between-two-strings-sometimes-doesnt-work)

Comment: Please provide a definition for "will not work". It's syntactically correct. "It is for numbers." --- nope

Answer (score 0):

What happens is, that your mySql is not aware about lakhs and crores and splits off the number part at the first space while auto-converting the formats. And then: The result is quite proper!

Besides the design pattern here (measure as part of the data field, normalization, ...) what is the relation between lakhs and crores ? How should mysql know that 1 crore is larger than 1 lakhs (ore vice cersa, I don't what this is).